# webfly adding admin user via docker-compose

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, wildfly

How do I add the run command within docker-compose file to enable admin user for Jboss/wildfly, my docker-compose file is under:

```
version: "3"
services:
  user:
    image: jboss/wildfly
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8000:8000
      - 9990:9990
    volumes:
      - ./User/target/:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
    container_name: "user"
    restart: always
    command: >
         bash -c "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin#007 --silent
         && /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0"
```

Reference: http://blog.arungupta.me/wildfly-admin-console-docker-image-techtip66/

but I still see the following screen prompting me to add user.

[image]

Comment: I just tested with that docker-compose.yml and it worked for me. Are you using http://localhost:9990?

Comment: yes, localhost:9990

Comment: is there a difference for simple war or war exploded, it works now?

Comment: There should not be no. The deployment should have no effect on the management console anyway.